# {!! Menu::render('admin-sidebar-menu', 'adminltecustom'); !!} Laravel, Admin LTE Sidebar Customization

Tags: laravel, sidebar, adminlte

{!! Menu::render('admin-sidebar-menu', 'adminltecustom'); !!}

I am editing a laravel code and want to make canges in my sidebar. but i donot understand this line, and I cannot find the source of sidebar.

Anyone who can help me out what does it actually means. and how can I edit my sidebar of the project.

Comment: can you tell me where this sidebar html file is located ?

Answer (score 1):

The blade Syntax `{!! !!}`

is used to used to print HTML as it is without escaping it.

Use it cautiously as it is used to avoid escaping data, and can be result in security failures if used incorrectly.

Comment: can you tell me where this sidebar html file is located ?